# Why Polynomial bijection between sets so important in mathematics?

Tags: polynomials, applications

From Wikipedia<sup>1</sup> The simple definition of bijection " In mathematics, a bijection, bijective function, or one-to-one correspondence is a function between the elements of two sets, where each element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set, and each element of the other set is paired with exactly one element of the first set." , Now many unsolved problems occurs in Algebra are related to the existence of bijection between sets , One of the best example is to test if there is a polynomial bijection between rational sets as mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/21003/51189),  What this can add to mathematics if really there is a bijection polynomial between rational sets? Does this gives new defined space   related to these family of polynomials such that it w'd contribute new properties in Algebra theory?

**Note:** The motivation of this question is to know consequences for both cases "existence- no-existence of Polynomial bijection from $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q$?

<sup>1</sup> Wikipedia: [Bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bijection&oldid=924462471))

Comment: I find the problem you discuss to be very interesting in its own right. It is definitely related to a lot of deep mathematics, but doesn't seem to be of much use itself. This is similar to the case of Fermat's last theorem, for instance.

Comment: @Wojowu ... agreed: this is an interesting problem.   But it is not true that: "Polynomial bijection between rational sets so important in mathematics".

Comment: @GEdgar, The title is very particular , but i meant why bijection polynomial is so interesting in general ? Probably i edit it to be general

Comment: @Wojowu FLT can be used to show that x,y,z in Beal's conjecture have no factor in common, and that A,B,C are not powers with common exponent.